# How to import jquery ui touch punch in Angular 2 Webpack app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angular, webpack, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have jQuery range slider widget that I import and use like this:

```
declare var jQuery: any;

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse';
```

and use it like this:

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#range-slider').slider({..});
```

My slider works fine.

The problem is that I need mobile touch enabled slider, so I imported **jQuery UI Touch Punch**:

```
declare var jQuery: any;

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse';
import 'jquery-ui-touch-punch';
```

but it errors with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Obviously it can't find **jQuery and jQuery UI**. But how do I pass jQuery to touch punch when imported jQuery is not on global scope?

I use [this](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) boilerplate for my project.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm struggling with this one right now...

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up using http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeslider/ instead which supports mobile touch events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me (sortable instead of slider but the same idea):

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';

(window as any).jQuery = $;
require('jquery-ui-touch-punch');
```

The require instead of import at the end is important. If you use an import the code that sets the jQuery global on window won't run until after the touch punch import since imports are run before everything else.

Comment: This approach seemed to have worked for me trying to implement draggable elements for FullCalendar in a webpack VueJS project without globally importing jquery